# How to override -F option on ls command under Mac OSX

Tags: macos

Generally I like the -F option - it quickly shows you what is a directory, what is executable etc. But it seems to be permanently on under Mac OS X (using the default ls command under 10.6.8 - I haven't installed GNU or anything). This prevents the output being filtered to another command that expects file names without the appended characters.

How do I change this behaviour?

thanks

Comment: Try http://apple.stackexchange.com as this is not a programming question.

Comment: It isn't like that under Mavericks. Is it an alias - try typing `which ls` and/or `alias ls`. If it is aliased, just use `\ls` to get the standard unaliased one.